# iwlwifi light blinking on Debian 8

Tags: wifi, iwlwifi

I'm trying to set the blink mode for `iwlwifi` on Debian 8.

I have created `iwlwifi.conf` in `/etc/modprobe.d` and added `options iwlwifi led_mode=1`, but this is not affecting the activity light.

The firmware is installed as part of `firmware-iwlwifi/oldstable`.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device in this instance is an iwl4965.

The correct way to disable the LED on this device is `options iwlegacy led_mode=1`

Hopefully, this will be useful for anybody trying to disable this activity on Debian 8 Jessie.

Answer (score 0):

I have a iwl3945 and to get the LED to blink, I needed to create the file:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/iwl3945.conf
```

with content

```
options iwl3945 led_mode=1
```

After this, I needed to:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r iwl3945 && modprobe iwl3945
```